# Mysql table with both primary and unique key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I have a mysql table like below,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sometable` (
  `field1` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `field2` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `field3` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `field4` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`field1`, `field2`)
  UNIQUE KEY `field3` (`field3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

At what context, a record to this table would be considered as a duplicate one? Assume that, I have the following record in my table.

```
-------------------------------------
| field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
|------------------------------------
|   a    |   b    |    c   |    d   |
-------------------------------------
```

Now if I insert `(field1,field2,field3,field4) values (a, b, cc, d)`, would it throw duplicate a key error? Or By considering the unique key constraint, would it allow the entry to be inserted and make the table looks like the below?

```
-------------------------------------
| field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
|------------------------------------
|   a    |   b    |    c   |    d   |
-------------------------------------
|   a    |   b    |   cc   |    d   |
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is going to through a duplicate record error if *either* of the unique key constraints are violated (the primary key counts as a unique key constraint).  So, if either `(field1, field2)` OR `(field3)` are repeated, you'll get an error.

So, your sample data would violate the constraints and inserting the second row would generate an error, because `(field1, field2)` are duplicated.

Comment: So it would not check for the constraints in a combined manner. Right?

Comment: @Mediocre correct, constraints are evaluated independently from each other.